# Auto-updating count of points in polygons?

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

I have a Point shapefile and a Polygon shapefile. Is it possible to create a field into the attribute table of the Polygon shapefile with the count of points inside each polygon, such that if I add a new point inside a polygon in a later moment the change is automatically reflected in the Count Field?

Comment: Possibly, but you may have to write some python code that reacts to an event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a way to do what I wanted using the plug-in refFunctions.

In the polygon layer, I created a virtual field with the expression `intersecting_geom_count('PointsLayerName')`. If I add or move points inside/outside the polygon the change is now automatically reflected into the Polygons layer field.

Answer (score 3):

1. In the vector layer properties, under the field tab, open the field calculator.
2. Set it as **new** and **virtual** field.
3. Name it as you wish.
4. And in the expression, enter `num_points(  $geometry )`

The field will be automatically updated. Although, when editing, the field is updated only when you actually commit the changes to the layer.

Comment: Following the steps you suggest what I get in the field is the number of vertices of each polygon, while what I need is the number of points (from another Points layer, called "Houses") that fall **inside** each polygon (Village).

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Will adapt the answer

Comment: I found out a way to do what I wanted using the plug-in refFunctions. In the polygon layer, I created a virtual field with the expression `intersecting_geom_count('PointsLayerName')`. If I add or move points inside/outside the polygon the change is now automatically reflected into the Polygons layer field. Thank you for your help!